# Having trouble with a Ruby rounding error

Tags: ruby, rounding, rounding-error

I can't for the life of me figure out why my: `generate_receipt` method is returning `54.9` for my "imported dinner plates item" when it should equal `54.65`. I wrote RSpec tests to confirm that the array is indeed returning the correct values.

```
47.50 + 4.75 + 2.40 = 54.65
```

Why is it returning `54.9` instead of `54.65`?! Where is this rounding up occurring? How do I get it to return the correct value? I'm stumped.

```
describe :calcualte_sales_tax do

  it "should return the correct array" do
    calculate_sales_tax(@receipt).should eq([0, 4.75])
  end

end

describe :calculate_import_tax do

  it "should return the correct array" do
    calculate_import_tax(@receipt).should eq([0.50, 2.40])
  end

end 

@receipt = {
    "1"=>{:item=>"imported chocolates", :price=>10.00, :quantity=>1},    
    "2"=>{:item=>"imported dinner plates", :price=>47.50, :quantity=>1}
    }

def generate_receipt(receipt)
  n = 0
  while n < receipt.length 
    receipt["#{n+1}"][:price]+=calculate_sales_tax(receipt)[n]
    receipt["#{n+1}"][:price]+=calculate_import_tax(receipt)[n]
    n+=1
  end
  receipt
end

def calculate_import_tax(receipt)
  taxes = []
  receipt.each do |k,v|
    if (v[:item] =~ /imported/)
      subtotal = v[:price]
      # v[:price]+=(((((5 * subtotal)/100)*20.ceil) / 20.0))
      # taxes<<(5 * subtotal)/100
      taxes<<((5 * subtotal/100)*20).ceil/20.0.round(2)
    else
      taxes<<0
    end
  end
  taxes
end

def calculate_sales_tax(receipt)
  tax_free_items = ["book", "chocolate bar", "chocolates", "pills"]
  taxes = []
  receipt.each do |k,v|
    if (v[:item] =~ /chocolate\s/) ||
      (v[:item] =~ /chocolates/) || 
      (v[:item] =~ /book/) || 
      (v[:item] =~ /pills/)
      taxes<<0
    else
      subtotal = v[:price]
      # v[:price]+=(((((10 * subtotal)/100)*20.ceil) / 20.0))
      # taxes<<(10 * subtotal)/100
      taxes<<((10 * subtotal/100)*20).ceil/20.0
    end
  end
  taxes
end
```

Comment: Tried adding .0 to every integer? Btw. 10 * X / 100 * 20 SHOULD be equal to 2 * X ... IF ruby treat it as floating point numbers that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def generate_receipt(receipt)
  n = 0
  while n < receipt.length
    puts receipt["#{n+1}"][:price].inspect
    receipt["#{n+1}"][:price]+=calculate_sales_tax(receipt)[n].round(2)
    puts receipt["#{n+1}"][:price].inspect
    puts calculate_import_tax(receipt)[n]
    receipt["#{n+1}"][:price]+=calculate_import_tax(receipt)[n].round(2)
    puts receipt["#{n+1}"][:price].inspect
    puts "-----"
    n+=1
  end
  receipt
end
```

Returns:

```
47.5
52.25
2.65
54.9
```

The bug is in your calculate_import_tax method. It's returning 2.65, not 2.40.

EDIT:

Got it :).

```
    receipt["#{n+1}"][:price]+=calculate_sales_tax(receipt)[n]
    receipt["#{n+1}"][:price]+=calculate_import_tax(receipt)[n]
```

Those rows are updating the price of the receipt. Hence, your tests are running independently, but the sales tax is modifying the raw price *before* the import tax is calculated...

Comment: If it's returning 2.65 how come the RSpec test isn't failing?

Comment: Actually, interesting, when you run the method alone it works...interesting. I'm betting on some crazy reference passing bug, investigating further now.

Comment: Updated answer - see what you think.

Comment: If this is the case then wouldn't cloning the receipt argument fix this issue? I tried that and it's still not working!

Comment: Nope. A ruby hash is a list of pointers to the values inside; hence, cloning the hash merely clones all the pointers to the same objects. The easiest way to do it is assign the prices to a variable called "new_price", and then set the receipt's price to that at the bottom of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ruby treat numbers without decimal part as INTEGERS. And WILL NOT create result that have decimal part unless computation include floating point number.

2) 10 * X / 100 * 20 == X * 2

3) LEGAL COUNTING may require specified accuracy, and so you may need to use specialized library for such number crunching.

Fast solution would be to change that code to:

10.0 * subtotal / 100.0 * 20.0

Now Ruby will treat all those numbers as float's.